# google analytics _anonymizeIp before _trackevent?

Tags: google-analytics

most of the examples for Google Analytics _anonymizeIp show its use before _trackPageview.

If my understanding is correct, it should also be used before _trackEvent?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use it more than once, similar to the `_setAccount` attribute. As long as you use the same tracker object for your entire page, the IP address should be anonymous.

You can see the example of usage on the [Google Analytics _gat object documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gat#_gat._anonymizeIp)

Comment: thank you, I see what you mean and I was using that reasoning for _tracktrans, which is mostly used after _trackviewpage, while _trackevent could potentially be used on its own. I guess this confirms that if _trackevent is used alone in the page, then we'd have _anonymizeIp before it?

Comment: @roboris You would need to call `_anonymizeIp` any time you create a new tracker. As a rule of thumb, if you use `_setAccount`, you'll need to call `_anonymizeIp` with it.